# Suppose $P$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and degree less than or equal to $7$.

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Question: Suppose $P$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and degree less than or equal to $7$. If the operator $D$ sends $p(x)$ in $P$ to its derivative $p'(x)$, what are the dimensions of the null space $n$ and range $r$ of $D$?

Solution:

This is what I was thinking:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
p(x)& p'(x)\\ \hline
x^7& 7x^6(\text{mod } 5) \equiv 2x^6\\ \hline
x^6& 6x^5(\text{mod } 5) \equiv x^5\\ \hline
x^5&  5x^4(\text{mod } 5) \equiv 0\\ \hline
x^4&  4x^3\\ \hline
x^3&  3x^2\\ \hline
x^2&  2x\\ \hline
x&  1\\ \hline
c&  0\\ \hline
\end{array}

Since there are two different $p(x)$'s that map to $0$, the null space of $D$ is $2$, and $8-2=6$, so the range of $D$ is $6$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. Summarising, the polynomial with a zero derivative in $\mathbf F_5[x]$ are polynomial s in $x^5$, i.e.  $\mathbf F_5[x^5]$. Withe the supplementary condition that it has degree $\le 7$, it is the $\mathbf F_5$-subspace generated by $1$ and $x^5$.

Comment: It generally is not enough to just see how many of the images are $0$; you would also need to make sure that the images of the other basis vectors are not linearly dependent! I mean, the map $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that sends $(a,b,c)$ to $(a+b+c,0,0)$ does not send any of the basis vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, nor $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,0)$, but the nullspace has dimension 2 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not enough. For instance, if $f\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ is defined by $f(x,y)=(x-y,-x+y)$, then $f(1,0),f(0,1)\ne(0,0)$, and so, by that argument, the dimension of the range of $f$ should be $2$; however, it is equal to $1$.

However, in thats case you are right, since the vectors $D(x^7)$, $D(x^6)$, $D(x^4)$, $D(x^3)$, $D(x^2)$, and $D(x)$ are linearly independent (this follows from the fact that they're polynomials with distinct degrees).